# Trying to find the second largest value in a column (postgres sql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to find the second largest value in a column and only the second largest value.

```
select a.name, max(a.word) as word
from apple a
where a.word < (select max(a.word) from apple a)
group by a.name;
```

For some reason, what I have now returns the second largest value AND all the lower values also but fortunately avoids the largest value.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Fix your question to say what rows you'd like returning (e.g. how many rows).  That would help.

Answer (score 28):

Here's another conceptually simple solution that's been running for me in .1 milliseconds on a table of 21 million rows, according to EXPLAIN ANALYZE. It returns nothing in the case where there's only one value.

```
SELECT a.name, 
(SELECT word FROM apple ap WHERE ap.name=a.name ORDER BY word ASC OFFSET 1 LIMIT 1) 
FROM apple a
```

Note that my table already had existing indices on name, word, and (name, word), which allows me to use ORDER BY like that.

Comment: This works great if the indexes are in place. Currently selecting 2000 rows from a table of 3 million.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest, albeit inefficient(array can exhaust memory):

```
select student, (array_agg(grade order by grade desc))[2]
from 
student_grades
group by student
```

The efficient one:

```
create aggregate two_elements(anyelement)
(
sfunc = array_limit_two,
stype = anyarray,
initcond = '{}'
);

create or replace function array_limit_two(anyarray, anyelement) returns anyarray
as 
$$
begin
    if array_upper($1,1) = 2 then
        return $1;
    else
        return array_append($1, $2);
    end if;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Test data:

```
create table student_grades
(
student text,
grade int
);



insert into student_grades values 
('john',70),
('john',80),
('john',90),
('john',100);


insert into student_grades values
('paul',20),
('paul',10),
('paul',50),
('paul',30);


insert into student_grades values
('george',40);
```

Test code:

```
-- second largest
select student, coalesce( (two_elements(grade order by grade desc))[2], max(grade) /* min would do too, since it's one element only */ )
from 
student_grades
group by student


-- second smallest
select student, coalesce( (two_elements(grade order by grade))[2], max(grade) /* min would do too, since it's one element only */ )
from 
student_grades
group by student
```

Output:

```
q_and_a=# -- second largest
q_and_a=# select student, coalesce( (two_elements(grade order by grade desc))[2], max(grade) /* min would do too, since it's one element only */ )
q_and_a-# from
q_and_a-# student_grades
q_and_a-# group by student;
 student | coalesce
---------+----------
 george  |       40
 john    |       90
 paul    |       30
(3 rows)


q_and_a=#
q_and_a=# -- second smallest
q_and_a=# select student, coalesce( (two_elements(grade order by grade))[2], max(grade) /* min would do too, since it's one element only */ )
q_and_a-# from
q_and_a-# student_grades
q_and_a-# group by student;
 student | coalesce
---------+----------
 george  |       40
 john    |       80
 paul    |       20
(3 rows)
```

**EDIT**
@diesel The simplest(and efficient also):

```
-- second largest
select student, array_min(two_elements(grade order by grade desc))
from 
student_grades
group by student;

-- second smallest
select student, array_max(two_elements(grade order by grade))
from 
student_grades
group by student;
```

The array_max function:

```
create or replace function array_min(anyarray) returns anyelement
as
$$
select min(unnested) from( select unnest($1) unnested ) as x
$$ language sql;

create or replace function array_max(anyarray) returns anyelement
as
$$
select max(unnested) from( select unnest($1) unnested ) as x
$$ language sql;
```

**EDIT**

Could be the simplest and efficient of all, if only Postgresql would make array_max a built-in function and facilitates LIMIT clause on aggregations :-) LIMIT clause on aggregation is my dream feature on Postgresql

```
select student, array_max( array_agg(grade order by grade limit 2) )
from 
student_grades
group by student;
```

While that LIMIT on aggregation is not yet available, use this:

```
-- second largest
select student, 

    array_min
    (

        array ( 
               select grade from student_grades 
               where student = x.student order by grade desc limit 2 )

    )

from 
student_grades x
group by student;


-- second smallest
select student, 

    array_max
    (

        array ( 
               select grade from student_grades 
               where student = x.student order by grade limit 2 )

    )

from 
student_grades x
group by student;
```

Comment: I debate the statement that anything involving pgplsql functions is 'simple'. ;)

Comment: @ijw: Don't worry, it's just a matter of time before the LIMIT clause on aggregate function will be available on Postgresql. For now, you have to roll your own way to do things ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is also brute force, but is guaranteed to only pass the table exactly and only once:

```
select name,word
  from (
         select name,word
              , row_number() over (partition by name 
                                       order by word desc)
                as rowNum
           from apple
       ) x
 where rowNum = 2
```

This version below may perform better if you have a covering index on (name,word) and there is a high count of word values per name:

```
with recursive myCte as
(
 select name,max(word) as word
      , 1 as rowNum
   from apple
  group by name
  union all
 select par.name
      , (select max(word) as word
           from apple 
          where name = par.name
            AND word < par.word
        ) as word
      , 2 as rowNum
   from myCte par
  where par.rowNum = 1
)
select * from myCte where rownum = 2
```

Comment: +1: But ROW_NUMBER is [PostgreSQL 8.4+](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/11/postgresql-emulating-row_number/)

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELEC name, 
        dense_rank() over (partition by name order by word desc) as word_rank,
        count(*) over (partition by name) as name_count
  FROM apple
) t
WHERE (word_rank = 2 OR name_count = 1)
```

**Edit**:
The `name_count = 1` takes care of those cases where only a single row is present for a specific name.

Using `dense_rank()` instead of `rank()` makes sure there *is* a row with word_rank = 2 as dense_rank makes sure there are no gaps

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Orable.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. 1) it is the database that you get when you strip the plastic off the shrink-wrap package that was labelled Oracle. 2) you have provided Orable functions (non-Standard SQL) which may not exist for PostgreSQL, OP's question.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: I **have** provided standard ANSI SQL that will run on PostgreSQL 8.4 and later (and unchanged on Oracle, DB2, Teradata and SQL Server btw).

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: "it is the database that you get when you strip the plastic off the shrink-wrap package that was labelled Oracle" -- oh dear, you have mistaken 'database' for 'DBMS'... "you have provided Orable functions (non-Standard SQL)" -- oh dear, you have failed to recognise SQL-99 functions.

Comment: @onedaywhen: The windowing functions are actually SQL-2003 not SQL-99 ;)

Comment: Are you sure? They pass the Mimer SQL-99 validator (http://developer.mimer.se/validator/parser99/index.tml) and a quick google for SQL-99 + dense_rank gets plenty of positive hits.

Comment: @onedaywhen: No, I'm not sure. I only checked the SQL-99 BNF definition (e.g. http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-99.bnf.html) and it does not list any keyword that relates to windowing functions (like *partition by* or *over*). But anyway: it **is** part of the standard ;)

Answer (score 0):

A very brute force query, but it works

```
select a.name, a.word
from apple a
where (select count(distinct b.word) from apple b
    where b.word > a.word) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, use RANK:

```
with ranking as
(
    select student, grade, rank() over(partition by student order by grade desc) as place
    from 
    student_grades
)
select * 
from
ranking
where 
    (student, place) 
    in 
    (
        select student, max(place)
        from ranking
        where place <= 2
        group by student
    )
```

Second to the MIN:

```
with ranking as
(
    select student, grade, 
        rank() 
        -- just change DESC to ASC
        over(partition by student order by grade ASC ) as place
    from 
    student_grades
)
select * 
from
ranking
where 
    (student, place) 
    in 
    (                
        select student, max(place) -- still max
        from ranking
        where place <= 2
        group by student
    )
```

Comment: I don't think the sub-select is needed when using rank(). Shouldn't `WHERE place = 2` be enough for the first version?

Comment: If indeed PostgreSQL *has* Rank().

Comment: @ahwnn: I just put it there so if there's no second(e.g. for George), it will return the first. Indeed can be rewritten without subquery, using `WHERE place=2` only @PerformanceDBA: Postgresql has Rank(), I made the code on Postgresql

Comment: @Michael.  In that case, if rank() is available, 3 selects and a cte is the long way to Denmark. Check the other answers.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: regarding 3 selects, I already commented(look at my comment @ahwnn) my code intent why I put the subquery(hence the 3 selects). What's the problem? It indeed can be reduced to 2 selects

Answer (score 0):

Umm, you don't just mean:

```
select a.name, max(a.word) as word
from apple a
where a.word < (select max(b.word) from apple b WHERE a.name = b.name)
group by a.name;
```

do you?  One row per name returning the second highest value per name (or no row if there is no second highest value).

If that's what you want, your query was just missing a constraint, although I suspect the above is probably two table scans if PostgreSQL has the sense to convert it to a JOIN.